# Boxplot displaying 2 groups

Tags: r, boxplot

Using this code :

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary)
boxplot(employ.data$employee, employ.data$salary)
```

I generated the box plot below :

[image]

How can I generate three box plots, 1 for each employee?

Comment: Are you open to non-base(graphics?) alternatives(`ggplot2`)?!

Comment: Is this what you're after `boxplot(salary~employee,employ.data)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon yes, thank you! whats the difference  betwen this and separating by commas ?

Comment: This is a formula that creates grouping. We map each salary to an employee.While in the code in the question we are plotting them independently.